# ACME certbot: Dry run is successful although no connection open

Tags: docker, certbot, acme

I have a question about `certbot`:

At the moment, I test it using the following command:

```
docker run -t --rm     
    -v nginx-docker_certs:/etc/letsencrypt
    certbot/certbot     
    certonly --dry-run --standalone
    -d mydomain.tld
```

When I run it, it fails because it cannot connect. So I add `-p 80:80 -p 443:443`:

```
docker run -t --rm     
    -v nginx-docker_certs:/etc/letsencrypt     
    -v nginx-docker_certs-data:/data/letsencrypt
    -p 80:80 -p 443:443
    certbot/certbot     
    certonly --dry-run --standalone
    -d mydomain.tld
```

Now it works.

**When I remove `-p 80:80 -p 443:443` again and do a test run again, the test run is successful. But why?**